# ANDROID - How to use google maps in drawer menu?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to do this to show a point on the map, but it's probably not that easy because I'm using drawer_menu with a fragment so the java files are split.

On line 35 I have error `Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager' in 'MapFragment'`

On line 38 I have another error `Method 'onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)' is never used`

**MapFragment.java**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    GoogleMap gMap;

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
    }
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
        gMap = googleMap;
        gMap.setOnMapClickListener(latLng -> {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Here");
            gMap.clear();
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
            gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        });
    }
}
```

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getChildFragmentManager() instead of  getSupportFragmentManager().

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
```

"Method 'onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)' is never used" ,you got this error because actually you did not override original onMapReady() function.So Android studio will consider this function as concreate method.So implement your fragment from OnMapReadyCallBack.

```
  public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
     supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```